# Is the $L'$ regular or not?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Suppose $L$ is regular and we define $L'=\{x:\exists y\in L \wedge \text{ y be a subsequence of x}\}$. Could we conclude that $L'$ is regular or not?

I think it's not regular because if $L=a^*b^*c^*$ then $L'$ could be $a^nb^nc^n$ so it can't be regular.

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way that invalidates an existing answer, after you've already received an answer.  I encourage you to take this as an encouragement to pay more attention to checking carefully that you have asked the question you want to ask, *before* posting your question, so you don't waste anyone's time providing an answer that isn't useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's actually regular.
Suppose $L$ is recognised by the DFA $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$, define the NFA $A' = (Q, \Sigma, \delta', q_0, F)$ s.t.

$$\delta'(q, a) = \{\delta(q, a)\} \cup \{q\}$$

for all $q \in Q, a \in \Sigma$.
Intuitively, you can think of $A'$ as being the same as $A$ with the addition that each state can reach itself using any character.
It is easy to see, that
$$(q, x) \vdash_{A'}^* (q, \varepsilon)$$
for all $q \in Q, x \in \Sigma^*$ and
$$(q, ax) \vdash_{A'} (q', x) \iff (q, ax) \vdash_A (q', x)$$
for $q' \neq q \in Q, a \in \Sigma$.
Using these properties it can be verified that
$$w = w_1w_2...w_n \in L(A)\iff a_0w_1a_1w_2...w_na_n \in L(A')$$
for some $a_i \in \Sigma^*$. Thus $L' = L(A')$ must be regular.

Comment: Hi, not sure how stuff like this works here but maybe it's not the best idea to change the question after it was flagged as duplicate 
This will prob. make it difficult for others to find your question.

Comment: Maybe consider creating a new post if you're sure that this hasn't been asked yet.